# stopService() not working

Tags: android, service

I have an IntentService that does the following:

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    while (true) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

The above is a sample of the code I am using. I intend to replace the println() with a HTTP Request sent to a server, but for now I am using this as a test. I call startService() as such:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    ConnectionUtility.getInstance().startService(this);
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    ConnectionUtility.getInstance().startService(this);
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    ConnectionUtility.getInstance().startService(this);
    super.onStop();
}
```

where my custom startService method does this:

```
public void startService(Activity activity) {
    if (!isMyServiceRunning(activity)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, BackgroundUpdateService.class);
        activity.startService(intent);
    }
}
```

Note: the isMyServiceRunning() method is a custom method I found elsewhere to determine if the Service is running. The method works as far as I know.

Now, the purpose of this Service is to trigger the println() whenever the particular Activity exits (either via onPause(), onDestroy() or onStop()), and when onCreate() or onResume() runs, the Service is to be stopped like so:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    ConnectionUtility.getInstance().stopServiceIfRunning(this);
    super.onResume();
}
```

Going one step deeper into stopServiceIfRunning():

```
public void stopServiceIfRunning(Activity activity) {
    if (isMyServiceRunning(activity)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, BackgroundUpdateService.class);
        activity.stopService(intent);
    }
}
```

Now here's the problem: I can start the Service alright, when I back out of the Activity via the Home/Back button or when I switch to a different Activity, the startService() method kicks in and it runs perfectly; that is to say, "Hello, World!" is printed every 5seconds as needed. But when I navigate back to the Activity, I can determine that my custom stopServiceIfRunning() method runs and the code enters the IF block fine (confirmed), but the service doesn't stop and the "Hello, World!"s just keep coming. What am I doing wrong?

---EDIT---
In response to Seraphim's comment:

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Activity activity) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (BackgroundUpdateService.class.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

But again, this method is returning true and false values accurately thus far, so I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: please post isMyServiceRunning() content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured out a way to do it, really really thankful to Seraphim for helping me out so much though.

I ended up overriding the onDestroy() method of my custom IntentService class. This is what I came up with:

```
public class BackgroundUpdateService extends IntentService {

    private boolean status;

    public BackgroundUpdateService() {
        super("BackgroundUpdateService");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }   

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        status = true;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while (status) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Hello, World!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        status = false;
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Evidently, the onDestroy() method is called whenever .stopService(intent) is called, so I made use of this fact to stop the while loop while I'm at it. This circumvents the reliability issue because each Service gets its own boolean variable and is not dependent on a static variable, and doesn't require any additional variables to be passed through the Intent.

Again, thanks to Seraphim for taking the time to help me out so much.

Answer (score 0):

Stopping services is not a synchronous operation. If your check for service termination is close to the previous "service stop" call, you may find your service is still running.

In my app when I need to stop services (when exiting app) I enter in a loop cycle (using AsyncTask) and wait for service termination.

I see you call

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    ConnectionUtility.getInstance().startService(this);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

I suggest to use `Application Context` for starting and stopping your service and not the `Activity` as a `context`. Because you're starting your service when the activity is going to be destroyed!

Also the part

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    while (true) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

A infinite loop when handling an intent? Sounds not very good to me.

Comment: Again, I don't think it has to do with my service termination check. It actually does enter the proper blocks of if conditions, I've ascertained this by printing random lines in between the code, and the line stopService() should have been called (I did a SOPL(1) and SOPL(2) immediately before and after, and both 1 and 2 appeared).

Comment: Did you try to wait for service termination before saying ""Hello, World!"s just keep coming"? In my app I see a couple of seconds between the stop call and the effective stop

Comment: Yeah, I usually terminate the app in about 10 or so more additional printouts. So unless the service takes longer than a minute to stop...

Comment: your're calling startService() in onDestroy()? is it correct?

Comment: I suggest to use ApplicationContext for starting stopping your service and not the Activity as a context

Comment: I did that... no change. :(

Comment: Please, in onHandleIntent don't use infinite loop. I'm not sure if Android call interrupt() when stopping service

Comment: I'm starting to think that's the case now... I've tried to print out the return from stopService(), and even that returns me true. How does one go about setting a background service that loops infinitely then?

Comment: Do your infinite loop with a check on the while (condition). Communicate to the service that you want to stop it and call stopSelf() form the service.

Comment: Maybe you want to try a LocalService pattern: look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample

Comment: Thank you, I came up with an alternative minutes before this. I actually tried it your way, but I realized that whenever startService() is called, a different Service is initiated altogether, and it seemed a lot of hassle to locate the same Service object again.

But again, thank you so much for being so helpful :)