# Can't stop Service from Preferences-Activity, which I started in other activity

Tags: android, android-service

I start an Activity in Android in my LoginFragment.class with this code:

```
startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), ClientActivity.class));
getActivity().finish();
```

You can see, that I kill the Fragment after starting the new Activity.
Now this Activity starts a Service itself with:

```
startService(new Intent(ClientActivity.this, MyTCPIPService.class));
```

Later, when a Button in my Preferences is clicked, I want to stop the Service.
I tried this:

```
Preference button = (Preference)findPreference("pref_logout");
button.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
        stopService(new Intent(getApplication(), MyTCPIPService.class));
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplication(), ClientActivity.class));
        finish();
        return true;
    }
});
```

The onDestrop() - Method of my MyTCPIPService.class is called, but the Service doesn't stop. 
Also I wonder how I can stop my ClientActivity.class before restarting it?

Maybe the mistake is, that I am creating a new intent when trying to stop the Service?
Can anyone help me here?

**Edit:**
I don't think that it is an duplicate to the reffered Question, because I do have an Async-Task in my Service, but in the onDestroy()-Method I cancel it and set the object within it is started to "null". So it shouldn't be the problem, that there is an infinite loop or an async-Task still running and holding the service up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [stopService() not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17399229/stopservice-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you close your `LoginFragment` with `getActivity().finish()`?
Use `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack()`, check `onDetach()` method in it.

What `service` are you using, `START_STICKY`/`START_NOT_STICKY`? Check `onTaskRemoved()` method in it. Try close `service` with `stopSelf()`.

Comment: Yes, I close it that way. Can you explain what I should do with popBackStack and oDetach? I am not sure about start_sticky/start_not_sticky. I just start the service with startService() (see my question)